# Converting latin-1 encoded UTF-8 string in Python

Tags: python, string, character-encoding

I'm using a Python 2.x-library `email` to iterate over some .eml-files, but I have Python 3.x installed.

I extract the filename in the header of each payload (attachment) using `.get_filename()`. Encoding is not set in the header and thus I believe Python 3.x interprets the returned `string` as `utf-8`. The `string` however looks like this, when it contains special characters, e.g. like "ø":

```
=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Sp=F8rgeskema=2Edoc?=
```

I have failed in numerous ways to convert this string into `utf-8` making it into bytes or not and de- and encoding using `latin-1`, `ISO-8859-1` (should be the same though) and `utf-8`.

I've also tried using:

```
ast.literal_eval(r"b'=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Sp=F8rgeskema=2Edoc?='")
```

and decoding that, but it still returns the original string containing the encoded characters.

How do one go about this?

Comment: This is not `ast`, this is RFC2047 with quoted-printable.

Comment: `email` is very much a part of Python 3, too. It was part of the standard library for a long time, though you'll notice that it got a significant overhaul in Python 3.6. If at all possible, you want to upgrade to at least 3.6.

Comment: The *proper* encoding to use in MIME attachment names is not RFC2047, but it is a sad fact of life that many email client authors don't know this. For the record, the proper standards-compliant specification is RFC2231.

Answer (score 2):

You are handling email, so you can use email handling functions:

Try with https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.header.html.
The last example (and second one, very small module:

```
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> decode_header('=?iso-8859-1?q?p=F6stal?=')
[(b'p\xf6stal', 'iso-8859-1')]
```

There is also a version for python 2.7.

So for your case:

```
subj = '=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Sp=F8rgeskema=2Edoc?='
subject, encoder = email.header.decode_header(subj)[0]
print(subject.decode(encoder))
```